# Less clicks to get to Notes in Outlook 365 on a PC

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I just discovered the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> shortcut to get to notes.

However, using the graphical interface and mouse, is there a faster way to get to notes when in email?

To get to notes in outlook, I have to click on the elipses (...) first, then the Notes icon.
[image]

Even though I widened the left window pane, the other two icons won't show unless I click the ...
Can you re-arrange these icons.  I would use Notes much more than TaskList.

Comment: what's preventing you from using the keyboard shortcut that you talked about?

Comment: @jsotola Cntl-F5 with my one hand (left) actually hurts a little (the keys are really too far apart for one hand), otherwise I have to take hand off mouse, too much movement.

Comment: I made an error in my answer. Some icons can go in the lower left icon space but not Note icon. My apologies. I look long and hard and do not see any way to do what you want.  Sorry.

Comment: @John - ok, just seems odd they don't let you drag them and arrange them, or create a shortcut or something.

Comment: Some of the icons can be rearranged which is why I answered but not the Note icon. I do not know why.